# "Unable to find a version of the runtime to run this application" running .NET app in virtual XP machine

Tags: .net, c, virtualbox, virtual-pc

I've written a few winform apps in .net 2.0 which won't run in a virtual XP (running from VirtualBox).

I get the error "unable to find a version of the runtime to run this application" (.NET Framework Initialization Error).

I've tried fixing the installation of .net and also installing v3.5. I think it's probably a security issue rather than a framework problem, but i'm running under an administrator account.

Other .net apps (2.0) run ok, so it might be a strong name/signing problem. I've tried compiling them completely unsigned and also delay signing them with a key and turning on verification skipping with the sn tool.

help greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

Since you tagged your question "c": have you remembered to install the "Visual C++ Runtime Libraries (x86)" prerequisity?

Answer (score 0):

does your application reference to assemblies written in .NET Framework 1.1? If so you will have to install Framework 1.1 as well